# Using Python to run nested string searches

Tags: python, string

I was wondering if there is an easy way of running nested searches for strings in a huge text file?

I have a text file which could contain a line of text to highlight a particular problem area.  I was looking into possible nested searches but also to avoid running a complete new search on the entire text file for an associated second string, but rather continue from the first string match point.

For example, if run a string search on a text file and I find a 'problem string', I was looking to then run a secondary or preferably a continued search (from the problem line) to find the first match of a second search string.  In my case the second search string would be to find the closest 'GPS INFO' string and then gather GPS info from the text file (i.e. the next consecutive GPS string to the first 'problem string').

I hope that makes sense?!?  Basically I want to avoid doing an entire new search of the text file but rather continue to search from where the first string was found.

I have some code below, but this just finds the first string, If I were to look for a second string I would normally begin new search, but then this doesn't guarantee I find the next consecutive string.

```
f = open(file, "r")    
searchlines = f.readlines()
searchstringsProblem = ['BIG Problem Line']
searchstringsGPSLoc = ['GPS INFO']

a = 0
tot = 0
row_num=0 # let it be current row number

while a<len(searchstringsProblem):
    for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
        for word in searchstringsProblem:
            if word in line:
                prob = line.split()
                worksheet.write(2,0,"Problem ID:", bold) 
                worksheet.write(2,1,prob[5]) 
                break
    a = a+1
```

Here's an example of the GPS INFO line plus following Stats I am looking to collect

```
Key line2 GPS Info

GPS = Active

Longitude = -0.00000

Latitude = +51.47700
```

Thanks for looking.

MikG

Comment: Are you only looking for one match or multiple matches? I.e. if you find one problem/GPS match then you are done or you want all pairs.

Comment: Hi Bob, just the first match for now, but I guess in future I'll probably want to find multiple matches (should there be several problem areas in the log file) so that I can plot a series of GPS coordinates on a map.

Comment: @MikG check out my answer, I've added support for finding the longitude and latitude lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the lines by just iterating through the file line by line instead of putting them all in a list with .readlines(). Something like the following might suit your needs (it will find all problems/gps pairs, note it will not find problems if there is no following gps pair):

File:

```
random
random
random
GPS INFO: 238939
random
BIG Problem Line
random
blah GPS INFO: 238490
random GPS INFO: 325236342
BIG Problem Line2
GPS INFO: 12343
```

Code:

```
searchstringsProblem = 'BIG Problem Line'
searchstringsGPSLoc = 'GPS INFO'
matches = []

with open("test.txt") as f:
    problem = False
    problem_line = ""

    for line in f:
        if not problem and searchstringsProblem in line:
            problem_line = line.strip()
            problem = True
        elif problem and searchstringsGPSLoc in line:
            matches.append((problem_line, line.strip()))
            problem = False

print matches
```

Which yields us:

```
[('BIG Problem Line', 'blah GPS INFO: 238490'), ('BIG Problem Line2', 'GPS INFO: 12343')]
```

If you wanted to keep track of the line numbers you could iterate through the lines with enumerate and then add that to the added value. Not sure how you wanted to store all the matches so I simply assumed a list[(problem,gps)] situation.

---

**EDIT:** Updated Supported for Longitude/Latitude per comments:

File:

```
random
random
random
GPS INFO: 238939
LONGITUDE: 123
LATITUDE: 321
random
BIG Problem Line
random
blah GPS INFO: 238490
LONGITUDE: 456
LATITUDE: 654
random GPS INFO: 325236342
LONGITUDE: 789
LATITUDE: 987
BIG Problem Line2
GPS INFO: 12343
LONGITUDE: 432
LATITUDE: 678
```

Code:

```
searchstringsProblem = 'BIG Problem Line'
searchstringsGPSLoc = 'GPS INFO'
matches = []

with open("test.txt") as f:
    problem = False
    problem_line = ""

    for line in f:
        if not problem and searchstringsProblem in line:
            problem_line = line.strip()
            problem = True
        elif problem and searchstringsGPSLoc in line:
            matches.append((problem_line, line.strip(), f.next().strip(), f.next().strip()))
            problem = False

for item in matches:
    print item
```

Output:

```
('BIG Problem Line', 'blah GPS INFO: 238490', 'LONGITUDE: 456', 'LATITUDE: 654')
('BIG Problem Line2', 'GPS INFO: 12343', 'LONGITUDE: 432', 'LATITUDE: 678')
```

---

**EDIT2:** Updated to ignore blank lines when finding longitude/latitude:

File:

```
BIG Problem Line

Key line2 GPS Info

GPS = Active

Longitude = -0.00000

Latitude = +51.47700
```

Code:

```
searchstringsProblem = 'BIG Problem Line'
searchstringsGPSLoc = 'GPS Info'
matches = []

with open("test.txt") as f:
    problem = False
    problem_line = ""

    for line in f:
        if not problem and searchstringsProblem in line:
            problem_line = line.strip()
            problem = True
        elif problem and searchstringsGPSLoc in line:
            latitude = ""
            longitude = ""
            for new_line in f:
                if "Longitude" in new_line:
                    longitude = new_line.split("=")[1].strip()
                elif "Latitude" in new_line:
                    latitude = new_line.split("=")[1].strip()
                if longitude and latitude:
                    break;

            if latitude and longitude:
                matches.append((problem_line, line.strip(), latitude, longitude))
                problem = False

for item in matches:
    print item
```

Output:

```
('BIG Problem Line', 'Key line2 GPS Info', '+51.47700', '-0.00000')
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, I have just tried it out and it works great!  Just one further question, in my earlier example I was enumerating the search lines so that I could jump down a couple of lines to gather further information.  In my text file I have a 'GPS Info' line, with the following line giving the 'Longitude' and the next line after that giving 'Latitude', I would then normally do a split on each line to extract the two GPS points, is this possible in your example to drop down a line or two?  I guess for now, rather than search for 'GPS Info' I can at least search for 'Longitude' to start with

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. You can go to the next line using `f.next()` which will jump the line one more and return a string of the next line. So if you're also looking for the next 2 lines after GPS INFO you can just use `f.next()` inside the elif loop and then do your split. Not sure what information you're trying to grab. Perhaps a short example file would help.

Comment: Hi Bob, I have added an example of the GPS Info and following lines I am looking to grab.  I have tried your update, and this looks to work, just I need to skip blank lines now.

Comment: Added another update, should fit your scenario based on the provided file.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Bob, this works perfectly.  Apologies for all my clueless questions, i'm still learning having moved to Python from Perl recently.  Your example should keep me busy for a while.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Added support to get longitude and latitude. 
**EDIT2:** Proper splitting.

You can add some enumerations or a counter if you want to keep track of which problem number (i.e. the 1st time the problem occurred, the 2nd time, etc.) it is, or an `else` to the current `if` to to write some text when you find the `Big Problem Line`.

```
def get_text_file(path):
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        searchstrings = ['BIG Problem Line', 'GPS INFO']
        current_string = 0
        for line in f:
            if searchstrings[current_string] in line:
                # That is, if the current index is 1 (you're looking for GPS info)
                if(current_string):
                    long_line = f.next()
                    lat_line = f.next()
                    long_value = long_line.split('=')[1]
                    lat_value = lat_line.split('=')[1]
                    some_write_function(long_value, lat_value) 
                current_string ^= 1 # Flips the bit (0^(1)=1, 1^(1)=0)
```

Comment: Thanks Al.Sal.  I can see your example partially working for my text file, I look into this a bit more

Comment: Let me know if there's anything going on that doesn't work with your text file.

Comment: Hi Al.Sal, It's finding the 'BIG Problem Line', but then when it goes on to search further in the text file for the GPS Info line it seems to stay at the 'BIG Problem Line' and then splits from there, there's a problem at the if(current_string): line.  So if 'BIG Problem Line' is found I need to go on and continue the search for the next 'GPS INFO' line, then start grabbing and splitting lines from this new point

Comment: Really? That's strange. It's working fine for me on a identically formatted file.